# How I can fix this? I explain in program

Tags: if-statement, compiler-errors, switch-statement

// i made 3 error in my program. and i want to all my error show up at the end. so if there any error, program show the error and close the console and else, will do the math

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            string color;
            string shipping;
            string error;

            int shirtCost;
            int shippingCost;
            int quantity;

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("  Welcome to Conestoga Online Shirts store");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine(" Please add your name:" + Environment.NewLine);
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "What colour would you like to buy " + name + "?" + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Green = $20, Blue = $20, Yellow = $10, Brown = $5, Other = $15" + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            color = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (color)
            {
                case "green":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your color is Green" + Environment.NewLine);
                    shirtCost = 20;
                    break;
                case "blue":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your color is Blue" + Environment.NewLine);
                    shirtCost = 20;
                    break;
                case "yellow":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your color is Yellow" + Environment.NewLine);
                    shirtCost = 10;
                    break;
                case "brown":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your color is Brown" + Environment.NewLine);
                    shirtCost = 5;
                    break;
                case "other":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your color is Other" + Environment.NewLine);
                    shirtCost = 15;
                    break;
                 default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    error = "Error: Choose the right color.";  //i want this error show up at the end
                    break;
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "How many would you like to order?" + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("!!!!!!!Notic: Customer cane choose Between 1 to 200!!!!!!!" + Environment.NewLine);
            quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if ((quantity >= 1) && (quantity <= 200))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your quantity is " + quantity + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                error = "Error: Choose the right Number."; //i want this error show up at the end
            }

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.WriteLine("What kind of shipping method you want to choose?" + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Expedited = $10, Standard = $5, None = $0");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            shipping = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (shipping)
            {
                case "expedited":
                    Console.WriteLine("Youe shipping is Expedited");
                    shippingCost = 10;
                    break;
                case "standard":
                    Console.WriteLine("Youe shipping is Standard");
                    shippingCost = 5;
                    break;
                case "none":
                    Console.WriteLine("Youe shipping is None");
                    shippingCost = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    error = "Error: Choose the right shipping method.";//i want this error show up at the end
                    break;
            }

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

// i want my error show up here. so if there are any error. show up the error and than close the console, but if there are not any error, will do the math.


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you declarating your string error, better's to use: `string error = ""`;
then in your case: `error = "My Error!";`

and write it:

```
Console.WriteLine(error);
Console.ReadLine(); //wait for input from keyboard.
```